# Error when attempting to extend and use Activity on Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I am attempting to utilize an `Activity` to enable Bluetooth on an Android device. The following is the class I have extended the `Activity` class with. I am receiving a `NullPointerException` error when the `startActivityForResult()` method is called. Any suggestions? Thank you!

```
public class Activities extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    protected void connectBluetooth(){
        Intent intentBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);

        startActivityForResult(intentBluetooth, 0); 
    }
}
```

The log output is as follows:

```
?:??: W/?(?): [ 09-09 18:08:38.497 15231:15246 W/System.err ]
?:??: W/?(?): java.lang.NullPointerException
?:??: W/?(?): [ 09-09 18:08:38.497 15231:15246 W/System.err ]
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
?:??: W/?(?): [ 09-09 18:08:38.497 15231:15246 W/System.err ]
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
?:??: W/?(?): [ 09-09 18:08:38.497 15231:15246 W/System.err ]
?:??: W/?(?):   at com.eyesore.bluetooth.Activities.connectBluetooth(Activities.java:28)
?:??: W/?(?): [ 09-09 18:08:38.497 15231:15246 W/System.err ]
?:??: W/?(?):   at com.eyesore.bluetooth.BluetoothModule.example(BluetoothModule.java:77)
?:??: W/?(?): [ 09-09 18:08:38.497 15231:15246 W/System.err ]
?:??: W/?(?):   at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Object.nativeFireEvent(Native Method)
?:??: W/?(?): [ 09-09 18:08:38.497 15231:15246 W/System.err ]
?:??: W/?(?):   at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Object.fireEvent(V8Object.java:60)
?:??: W/?(?): [ 09-09 18:08:38.497 15231:15246 W/System.err ]
?:??: W/?(?):   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.doFireEvent(KrollProxy.java:636)
?:??: W/?(?): [ 09-09 18:08:38.497 15231:15246 W/System.err ]
?:??: W/?(?):   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.handleMessage(KrollProxy.java:831)
?:??: W/?(?): [ 09-09 18:08:38.497 15231:15246 W/System.err ]
?:??: W/?(?):   at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleMessage(TiViewProxy.java:307)
?:??: W/?(?): [ 09-09 18:08:38.497 15231:15246 W/System.err ]
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
?:??: W/?(?): [ 09-09 18:08:38.497 15231:15246 W/System.err ]
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
?:??: W/?(?): [ 09-09 18:08:38.497 15231:15246 W/System.err ]
?:??: W/?(?):   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime$KrollRuntimeThread.run(KrollRuntime.java:104)
?:??: W/?(?): [ 09-09 18:08:38.497 15231:15231 E/TiJSError ]
?:??: W/?(?): (main) [6,293329] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
?:??: W/?(?): [ 09-09 18:08:38.497 15231:15231 E/TiJSError ]
?:??: W/?(?): (main) [0,293329] - In app.js:71,12
?:??: W/?(?): [ 09-09 18:08:38.497 15231:15231 E/TiJSError ]
?:??: W/?(?): (main) [0,293329] - Message: Uncaught Error: Java Exception occurred
?:??: W/?(?): [ 09-09 18:08:38.497 15231:15231 E/TiJSError ]
?:??: W/?(?): (main) [0,293329] - Source:   bluetooth.example();
?:??: W/?(?): [ 09-09 18:08:38.517 15231:15246 E/V8Exception ]
?:??: W/?(?): Exception occurred at app.js:71: Uncaught Error: Java Exception occurred
```

Manifest file below -

```
<manifest>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE"/>
        <application>
            <activity android:name=".Activities" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>            
</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the LogCat output from the crash, please?

Comment: Certainly. Please see the updated post.

Comment: Alright, when do you call `connectBluetooth`? You should be calling it from `onCreate`.

Comment: I see. I was calling it from another class where I instantiated the Activities object:


Activities testActivities = new Activities(); 

testActivities.connectBluetooth();

Comment: Oh my, no, you should never ever ever ever create an `Activity` using `new`. Ever. I'll try to summarize this in an answer for you...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments in the OP, you are not starting the `Activity` properly. You should **never ever ever** start an `Activity` using `new`.

Firstly, your `Activites` should look like this, calling `connectBluetooth()` on its own.

```
public class Activities extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        connectBluetooth();
    }
    protected void connectBluetooth(){
        Intent intentBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);

        startActivityForResult(intentBluetooth, 0); 
    }
}
```

When an Android app starts, it runs the main `Activity`, which is [defined in the manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631982/change-applications-starting-activity-android). **if `Activities` is your main `Activity`**, then no further code will be required.

However, I get the hunch that this is a second `Activity`, which is started from somewhere else. So let's say you have this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Activities testActivities = new Activities(); // This is bad!
        testActivities.connectBluetooth(); // This too!
    }
}
```

What you should be doing instead, is this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Activities.class)); // Starts an Activity properly
    }
}
```

This will start your `Activity`, call `onCreate`, and create your Bluetooth connection properly. You should read [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html) on the `Activity` lifecycle.

Comment: This is only a proof of concept on my part, so there are actually not any other activities, currently. I've dropped in the subsection of my manifest file above, would you mind confirming this looks accurate? Thank you very much.

Comment: That looks right. From where are you calling `Activities testActivities = new Activities();`?

Comment: I was calling it from the main class in this module. The only other logic in that class (or in this module at all, currently) was testing to see if Bluetooth was enabled, and if it was not, I was attempting to fire that off. I suppose the logical thing to do would be to move that logic into the connectBluetooth() method.

Comment: Absolutely. So, use the first block of code I provided in this post (don't call the `Activities` from elsewhere), then move any checks/error handling into the `connectBluetooth()` method.

Comment: Understood! Well, from all appearances this should be working. I'm getting no errors anywhere, but it also appears that the Activity is never firing off.