# samsung loading screen on running an emulator

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to run an android app from the eclipse using many kind of emulators (nexus s, 7 etc..) but the emulator never pass the "samsung loading screen"
Here is a picture to describe what I mean: http://oi47.tinypic.com/ei5vf4.jpg
I tried to include as many as possible details in that picture.

Thanks.

edit:
Since I have some red lines in my console i edited my post, this is the console log:

```
[2012-11-18 00:00:06 - myFirstAndroidApp] ------------------------------
[2012-11-18 00:00:06 - myFirstAndroidApp] Android Launch!
[2012-11-18 00:00:06 - myFirstAndroidApp] adb is running normally.
[2012-11-18 00:00:06 - myFirstAndroidApp] No Launcher activity found!
[2012-11-18 00:00:06 - myFirstAndroidApp] The launch will only sync the application           package on the device!
[2012-11-18 00:00:06 - myFirstAndroidApp] Performing sync //after this line I choose the device in this case nexus s
[2012-11-18 00:00:18 - myFirstAndroidApp] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device     'AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google'
[2012-11-18 00:00:18 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-11-18 00:00:18 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
[2012-11-18 00:00:18 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-11-18 00:00:18 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES    emulation, using software renderer.
[2012-11-18 00:00:18 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-11-18 00:00:18 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-11-18 00:00:18 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-11-18 00:00:18 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-11-18 00:00:18 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-11-18 00:00:18 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-11-18 00:00:19 - myFirstAndroidApp] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-11-18 00:00:19 - myFirstAndroidApp] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to  be launched...
```

Comment: Are you running the emulator inside a VM?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean but I ran it from eclipse which I downloaded from android development site with the android sdk.

Comment: Here is a picture to show the ide: [link](http://tinypic.com/r/2ag14y9/6)

Comment: Hey guys I really need your help so I hope this comments bump my thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Run -> Run Configurations

If "Launch Default Activity" is selected, make sure you have a LAUNCHER in AndroidManifest.

If not, make sure you pick an Activity in "Launch".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I did marked the "launch default activity", so how can I check if I got a launcher in androidmanfiest?btw I'm running an example of anroid which is LoginActivity but I got the same result for custom classes.

Comment: Wierd when I open an hello world project I do have an activty and it works, maybe there is something wrong in the android samples. I can run it now on my real device but on the avd the result stays the same.

Comment: There is no default activity in that manifest. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631982/change-applications-starting-activity-android or this: http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-set-default-activity-for-android-application/