# Can't start application after replacing main activity in Android

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-activity

I renamed my `MainActivity` class to `DataActivity` and added a new main activity class with IntelliJ IDEA. I changed the `AndroidManifest.xml` file to the following:

```
 <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <activity android:name=".DataActivity"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

I uninstalled the app from my phone and deleted the compiler cache. At install, I get the following exception:

> Launching application:
> com.example.DataTest/com.example.DataTest.DataActivity.
>
> DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n
> "com.example.DataTest/com.example.DataTest.DataActivity"
> -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent {
> act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
> flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.DataTest/.DataActivity }
> from null (pid=5882, uid=2000) requires null

What else should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631982/change-applications-starting-activity-android) helped me where to look. In the comments, [zeh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/439026/zeh) claims that the SDK holds a refence to the original activity. I checked the launch configuration, and in my IDEA it has been altered from "Launch default activity" to "Launch activity: DataActivity".
It works now okay.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this to include the intent filters with your new main activity:

```
<activity android:name=".DataActivity"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

and remove "MainActivity" if it no longer exists. i.e. delete this:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

Comment: You misunderstood me. I want MainActivity to be the main activity that's why I renamed the original to DataActivity. I can't remove it.

Comment: You are trying to launch the app from "DataActivity" in your shell command line. You cannot launch into any activity but the one that has the action "MAIN"