# Android Studio - Change default application layout load

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have a android studio project, 
and I have got few layouts which are connected to their .java files

note "I couldn't post images as of my low reputation"

I have got:

1. layout1.xml
2. layout2.xml
3. layout3.xml
4. layout4.xml
5. layout5.xml

and

1. Layout1.java
2. Layout2.java
3. Layout3.java
4. Layout4.java
5. Layout5.java

Android Manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/blablabla"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:name="com.icetea09.demomaterialdesigndrawermenu.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

layout1.xml code is this: "activity_main.xml is my layout1"

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mLvDrawerMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_drawer_menu);

    List<DrawerMenuItem> menuItems = generateDrawerMenuItems();
    mDrawerMenuAdapter = new DrawerMenuItemAdapter(getApplicationContext(), menuItems);
    mLvDrawerMenu.setAdapter(mDrawerMenuAdapter);

    mLvDrawerMenu.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, mToolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        setFragment(0, BikeFragment.class);
    }
}
```

The default layout load view is "layout1.xml with Layout1.java"

The question is how do I change the start view layout from layout1 to layout2.
Like when I install the app first, It will show the "layout2.xml" view instead of default one which is layout1.xml in my case.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: show AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I have edited and now you can see the androidmanifest too, thanks

Comment: ok, show how you use for example :Layout1.java

Comment: I don't see any activity Layout1 in your manifest file. What exactly is Layout1 is it a fragment?

Comment: Ahh so I have to declare it in the androidmanifest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to do it, is when you add a new activity. You can click on "Launcher Activity". Then Android Studio will make this new activity the Launcher Activity.

When you already have added both activities there is another way.

The best way is to use the

```
AndroidManifest.xml
```

file. To make an activity seen as a launcher activity you add the following attributes to your activity in the manifest:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

This question may be a duplicate: [change application's starting activity - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631982/change-applications-starting-activity-android)

Comment: E. Verdi I will try it now, and I will tell you if it worked, thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you E. Verdi, it is working now, I will vote up once i reach 15rep.

Comment: Ok, no problem. We are all here to help each other :)
Glad it worked.