# How to join 2 APKs into 1 APK?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I'm working with a video app and a chat app which have already been built separately.

Now I'm trying to join those two into one APK, which creates a launcher with two options: whether to use the chat app, or the video app.

Comment: Please provide more information about what you are trying to achieve, and what you have attempted so far.

Comment: What do you mean by saying `join 2 APKs`? How to merge the source code? Give us more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a launcher, an apk with two top activities is a valid use case, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3632061/755804

In theory, if there is no conflict in class names or resources, you can just place both into the same directory tree (the exact location will will depend on whether you use Android Studio or Eclipse/ADT).

If you have no source, you can *baksmali* the apps, but I think that you will likely have resource id conflicts.

But why on Earth you need two applications in the same apk?