# How to change first activity in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to change my first activity, first I have activity named **MainActivity**. And I add new activity named **ActivityFirst**. Surely I have to change **AndroidManifest.xml**. Previously I have androidManifest like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="edmt.dev.androidsimsimi">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And after I add my new activity, also I change my androidManifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="edmt.dev.androidsimsimi">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ActivityFirst">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I'm confused where I put the MainActivity after I add ActivityFirst. This my **ActivityFirst.java**:

```
public class ActivityFirst extends AppCompatActivity {

  private Button mulai;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

    mulai = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mulai);

    mulai.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityFirst.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe this is a helpful link? [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631982/change-applications-starting-activity#3632061)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `<activity>` tags for each Activity in your app's manifest file as mentioned [here in the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html):

> All activities must be represented by  elements in the
>   manifest file. Any that are not declared there will not be seen by the
>   system and will never be run.

So in your case, it'd be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="edmt.dev.androidsimsimi">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ActivityFirst">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Android, The first Activity to show when a app is launched is tagged `LAUNCHER` in your manifest file.

All you need do to change the Launcher Activity is to add an `intent-filter` tag inside the activity tag.

So if your activity tag was self closing, you change it and add intent filter tag inside the tag.

Here is an illustration.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
<activity android:name=".ActivityFirst">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The above code in your Manifest will make ActivityFirst the launcher activity,

while the below code will make MainActivity the launcher activity.

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityFirst" />
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

I hope this helps.