# Changing Another Activity to Main Activity & New Project - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I had an existing project in Android Studio which I copied because I want another project with a different name, but I also still want everything else to be the same (I want to add to the previous project). I'm having trouble figuring out where to go to rename just the project. I'm using a Macbook and I went to File & Edit but I don't see rename anywhere. I'm using the newest version of Android Studio incase it's different on other versions. Is renaming done differently on MacOS?

Something else I was having trouble understanding is the MainActivity. After I copied the existing project to my new one, I want another activity I have to be the MainActivity, not the one from the previous project. Is is possible to change which one is the MainActivity?

Comment: change the main intent in your manifest. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631982/change-applications-starting-activity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change application's starting activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631982/change-applications-starting-activity)